# Why is it giving the error-cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object

Tags: python, pandas

The fill function is to fill all the non-available data in titanic with the average age of that particular class of passengers

```
titanic['Age']=titanic[['Age','Pclass']].apply(fill,axis=1) 

sex=pd.get_dummies(titanic['Sex'],drop_first=True)

embarked=pd.get_dummies(titanic['Embarked'],drop_first=True)

titanic.drop(['Cabin','Embarked'],axis=1,inplace=True)

titanic.dropna(inplace=True)

titanic=pd.concat(['titanic','sex','embarked'],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
titanic=pd.concat([titanic,sex,embarked],axis=1)
```

instead of:

```
titanic=pd.concat(['titanic','sex','embarked'],axis=1)
```

A side note however:
If you're just trying to drop `NaN` values and get dummies you can do it on the original dataframe without having to use [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html).

example:

```
titanic = pd.get_dummies(titanic)
```

and just drop NaN values with [dataframe.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
titanic.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for telling about how to get dummies in the original data frame but in my programme it will create unnecessary columns but still thanks for the new valuable info

Answer (score 2):

pd.concat expects you to give list of dataframe as parameter not a list of  strings. Change your code to

```
titanic=pd.concat([titanic,sex,embarked],axis=1)
```